# XOR всех чисел в массиве для получения суммы элементов массива

Tags: c, битовые-операции, xor

В [этой](https://habr.com/post/243819/)
статье есть в первой задаче говорится о том,что можно найти сумму массива ,используя XOR.Так же и я хочу поступить,но ответ неверен.Как посчитать сумму всех чисел , используя XOR?

```
int a[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(i+1!=5)
        sum=sum+a[i]^a[i+1];
        else break;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
```

Comment: В этой задаче такого не говорится. Xor и сумма - альтернативные способы решения задачи о недостающем элементе

Comment: @Elvin Я статью не читал, но очевидно, что если целочисленный массив содержит два элемента, каждый из которых равен 1, то выражение sum=sum+a[i]^a[i+1]; будет равно 0 вместо 2.:)

Comment: @MBo,как тогда можно реализовать то, о чём они говорят, используя xor, можете описать алгоритм?

Comment: количество элементов известно. Значит, можем проксорить все числа от 1 до N. Потом проксорим все заданные числа. Очевидно, что ксор двух полученных чисел и даст искомое недостающее.

Comment: @Elvin Нужно иcпользовать свойство xor - xor числа с собой же даёт ноль